# Clone repository failed error

Tags: git, repository, git-clone

I have a problem where I try to clone a repository and i'm getting the following error message:

> fatal: curl_global_init failed

and this is what i'm trying to do:

```
$ git clone http://10.0.50.168:10000/WSW.git
```

it also happen when i'm trying to clone something from Github as well.

Full Output:

```
administrator@Hostname MINGW64 ~/Desktop/test
$ git clone http://10.0.50.168:10000/WSW.git
Cloning into 'WSW'...
fatal: curl_global_init failed
```

can someone know what might be the issue?

Comment: Can you give us the full output of the command? Also, this doesn't really seem like a programming question, and it may be better suited for another SE site.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: What the output of `git --version`?

Comment: `git version 2.18.0.windows.1`

Comment: The only thing left I can think of is to try `curl`ing comething else over https, say this: `curl  https://stackoverflow.com -o testSO.html`

Comment: @ThomasJager its working when i'm `cURL` what you wrote, only after i switched some of the `curl` files in Git folder with new ones from https://curl.haxx.se , but still when try to clone the repository it give the same error.

* maybe because it's installed on Windows Server 2016? does Git support this OS ?

Comment: @Eitanmg: that's not a bad guess, but if you're using "Git for Windows", then that should be supported: https://gitforwindows.org/requirements.html (if you're using another git distribution, you'll have to check with them).